# How to initiate rsync transfer from one server to another through ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line, rsync

I'm trying to easily move some data with `rsync` from one server to another without actually connecting manually and doing all that, but only giving the IPs as arguments.

```
# -- Variables
my_key="my_key"
new_ct="${2}"
old_ct="${1}"

# -- SHH key generation on the localhost
mkdir /tmp/keys/
cd /tmp/keys
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f /tmp/keys/id_ed25519 -q -N ""; \

# -- Copy the keys on the old_ct
scp -P 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ${HOME}/.ssh/${my_key} \ /tmp/keys/id_* root@${old_ct}:~/.ssh/

# -- Copy the key to new_ct and write it to authorized_keys file
scp -P 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ${HOME}/.ssh/${my_key} \
/tmp/keys/id_ed25519.pub root@${new_box}:~/.ssh/
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${new_ct} -p 2222 -i ${HOME}/.ssh/${my_key} \
"cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

# -- Lastly, start the rsync transfer on the old_ct in a detached screen session
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${old_ct} -p 2222 -i ${HOME}/.ssh/${my_key} \
"
screen -dmLS "migrating.localdata.to.newCT" \
bash -c "rsync -azvhHSP --stats -e \
'ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
/home/user root@${new_ct}:/home"
"
  
# -- Remove the keys
rm -rf /tmp/keys
```

The last part of the script, the part with `rsync` is the one that doesn't work. The rest works flawlessly.

##### I do need those double quotes `""` wrapping the entire bash command that will be running inside the screen session as well as those single quotes `''` for the ssh options which `rsync` needs.

#### My question is how to put them all in such a way that it all works?

Comment: Your problem is that your last rsync part is inside single quotes, so the `${new_ct}` variable doesn't get expanded. Try putting single quotes around it to be excluded from the quoting. Also for easier debugginh, add `echo` before the entire command to ensure it looks like you want it to look like.

Comment: BTW, you have additional single quote pair inside the bigger ones (`'ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'`) that might also affect the command, because I think they are actually "excluded" from the entire big block inside the quotes, because the first single quote "closes" a pair with the first single quite of the block, and the second one "opens" a new pair with the last single quote at the end of the block. So the part between might no even be quoted. That's why I suggested ti add `echo` to view the expected command.

Comment: Completely understood what you're saying :) Thanks a lot. Yes, that was a rookie mistake

Comment: So this is the exact command that I need to run in the remote shell via ssh: `screen -dmLS "migrating.localdata.to.newCT" bash -c "rsync -azvhHSP --stats -e 'ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /root/user root@${new_ct}:/root"`. I'm trying to figure out what do I need to tweak for this to work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double quotes **inside** the double quotes  (for instance, `"migrating.localdata.to.newCT"`). You need to escape the internal double quotes to be treated literally.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${old_ct} -p 2222 -i ${HOME}/.ssh/${my_key} \
"
screen -dmLS \"migrating.localdata.to.newCT\" \
bash -c \"rsync -azvhHSP --stats -e \
'ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
/home/user root@${new_ct}:/home\"
"
```

By the way, you don't have to run `bash -c` after screen. You can just add the command and the arguments after the screen, and it will run them. This will save you some nested quotes and the escaping.

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${old_ct} -p 2222 -i ${HOME}/.ssh/${my_key} \
"
screen -dmLS 'migrating.localdata.to.newCT' \
rsync -azvhHSP --stats -e \
'ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' \
/home/user root@${new_ct}:/home
"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is so funny. I tried escaping lots of things with this one but didn't think of those double-quotes. Haha, this is so logical.